# Port open just for 1 domain (vHost Apache2)

Tags: apache, port, vhosts

I got the issue that the ISPConfig panel is showing on every domain which is hostet on my Server... For example if i have www-example-com on my webserver and i go to www-example-com:1234 (my own port) then ISP login appears, I want the ISPCONFIG Panel just on 1 Domain (my-desiredDomain-com:1234). how can i Fix this?

my ispconf.vhost:

```
    Listen 1234

    <VirtualHost *:1234>

ServerName my-desiredDomain-com

... // nothing interesting

</virtualHost>;


<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www-example-com
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks for your Help 
PS: Replace "-" with "."

Answer (score 0):

For the port openning is Listen Portnumber. 
As for the domains everything is done via Virtualhost and distinquish via ServerName and DocumentRoot directives plus the other.

Sorry your request is no complete in order to help you more. Please put full configuration where you can hide the servername/domai

You have to add a second VirtualHost directive next to the ispconfig like

```
Listen 1234

<VirtualHost *:1234>

ServerName my-desiredDomain-com

... // nothing interesting

</virtualHost>;

Listen 80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www-example-com
</VirtualHost>
```

I am on mobile an can insert the code quotes.. so is missing s
the smaller sign

So for each additional new VirtualHost directive and so on.

Comment: for my example.com (which is my desired Domain to listen on 1234) : 

Listen 1234 <br>
&lt;VirtualHost *:1234&gt;<br>
  ServerName my.example.com<br>

  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost<br>
  &lt;Directory /var/www/ispconfig/&gt;<br>
 
  &lt;/Directory&gt;<br>
&lt;/VirtualHost &gt;<br>

for my other Domain.com (which should not redirect to /var/www/ispconfig): 

&lt;VirtualHost *:80&gt;<br>

                 documentRoot /var/www/somewhere<br>    

                ServerName otherDomain.com<br>    
   &lt;VirtualHost &gt<br>

Comment: I think you didn´t understand exactly what the problem is, maybe i explained it a little  bad.. I´ll try again: I made the Config for my Servername my.example.com on port 1234 but on other Domains where I just put Port 80/443 as Vhost I can reach them on Port 1234 too. I just want the port 1234 on the Domain my.example.com not on the others.

Comment: ok now I understand your issue add 'Listen 80' below 'Listen 1234' without brackets and restart the apache